# Hosting in IIS local nuget server Method Not Allowed 405

Tags: iis, server, nuget

I am trying to get local nuget server with the help of following link.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/872230/Create-Your-Own-Private-NuGet-Server-in-Windows-Az

Its hosted without much issue and I can view the hosting page. However when I try to publish a package to this nuget server it throws 405 error (Method not allowed).

I know this is something to do with IIS setting as I try it using IISExpress and it publishes ok.

All above is on local iis server (not on azure or any other remote server).

Any idea?